# Kotlin #toCharArray giving wrong characters

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to loop through characters of a string. While doing so I found out that the `#toCharArray` function doesn't split special characters correctly. Here is my testing code:

```kotlin
val text = "\uD835\uDC9C"
text.toCharArray().forEach {
  println(it)
}
```

Is giving me the following response

```
?
?
```

So it seems like that it thinks that `\uD835\uDC9C` are 2 separate characters. But it should return only a single element .

Does anyone know how to get the correct character out of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, a Kotlin `Char` is 16-bit, and so characters outside of the basic multilingual plane needs to be represented with 2 `Char`s (surrogate pairs). One `Char` is not enough.

If you want to loop through all the Unicode *codepoints* in the string, use `codePoints`, which gives you an `IntStream`:

```
text.codePoints().forEachOrdered { 
    println(it)
}
```

This will print one line containing the integral code point of "", as expected.

If you want to actually *see* "", you will need to convert the integer code point to a `String`. Recall that it can't be put into a `Char`.

```
text.codePoints().forEachOrdered {
    println(String(intArrayOf(it), 0, 1))
    // or println(Character.toString(it)) if you don't mind using java.lang.Character
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was already trying to convert the string to UTF-32. No success though. Thanks for your idea. Using the `codePoints` function works for my use case, since I need the codepoint later too. Thank you!

Comment: Java primitive char is also 16-bit, so it's not Kotlin specific.
In case you want to detect surrogate pairs to handle them properly:
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-surrogate-pair.html

Comment: The technical term for this is [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) (an encoding in which Unicode characters up to U+FFFF are represented directly as two bytes, and others are represented as a surrogate pair of 2 two-byte characters).

Answer (score 0):

That's a surrogate pair. They can't be stored in a single character. What's the problem with printing it as a string?

```
val text = "\uD835\uDC9C"
println(text)
```

This prints the character you want. And if you have multiple characters in your string you can just split the string by every second backslash and create a list.

Comment: My example code didn't include all things I wanted to do. In my further code I have some if condition which have to run for every character. That's why I needed an char array.